# Mysql 2 Foreign key with both uniques value

Tags: mysql

i have `members` table has 2 fields `userid` *(foreign key)* and `groupid` *(foreign key)*, you can see below :

```sql
--------------------------
|  userid  |   groupid   |
--------------------------
|    102   |     G10     |
|    103   |     G20     |
|    104   |     G50     |
--------------------------
```

what i expect we can't insert same value (`userid`, and `groupid`). but we can insert the value if `userid` or `groupid` is different.

e.g :

```sql
# Case 1 :
INSERT INTO `members` VALUES ('102', 'G10');
# failed, because there is userid with value 102 and groupid with value  G10

# Case 2 :
INSERT INTO `members` VALUES ('102', 'G20');
# success, because there is nothing userid 102 with groupid G20

# Case 3 :
INSERT INTO `members` VALUES ('104', 'G10');
# success, becuase there is nothing userid 104 with groupid G10
```

thank you, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Add a unique index on `(userid, groupid)`?

Answer (score 0):

Alter table members add unique(userid,groupid);